# fetching multiple images from url of xml response in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can anyone guide me how to load images through image_url tags in my image control named BOOK_URL under a loop? i have fetched other book info under similar_books tag of each book tag but unable to fetch images of all book tags in my image control.

My code looks like this.

```
  var xdoc = XDocument.Load("https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&title=" + title.Text);


        IEnumerable<XElement> allElements =
                 xdoc.Descendants("similar_books").Descendants("book");

        foreach (XElement result in allElements)
        {
        BOOK_URL.Source = BOOK_URL.Source + "\n"+ 
       ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(result.Element("image_url").Value)) ;                
          search.Text = search.Text + "\n" +

             " Book Name:  " + result.Element("title").Value + "\n" +
                 " ISBN:   " + result.Element("isbn").Value + "\n" +
                 "Average Ratings:  " + result.Element("average_rating").Value + "\n";

        }
    }
```

Also my url of xml response look like this:

https://www.goodreads.com/book/title.xml?key=Uxb0zPb86N4STVy2ECWYA&title=DUNE

i am getting all info except for images. Please help me to fetch all images of all book tags as i have fetched other book info rather than images.

Comment: is `BOOK_URL` your `Image` control?  How do you expect to display more than one image in a single control?

Comment: i just want to fetch all images of all book tags that are inside similar_books tag. since i have fetched other book info iteratively of all book tags so i have to fetch their respective images too. but i dont know how to fetch all of their images. can you guide me?

Comment: in your for loop you are already getting all "image_url" values.  Or just use another LINQ query to get the "image_url"  - `xdoc.Descendants("similar_books").Descendants("book").Descendants("image_url");`

Comment: I was also thinking that I am getting all image_url values but unfortunately I am getting text values only as output and not the images. 

Comment: Is my statement of BOOK_URL.source correct under loop?

Comment: No it is not.  And as I noted earlier, you cannot display multiple images in a single Image control.

Comment: So how can I display multiple values of image_url tags under loop in image control or anywhere else.. I just wanted to display all values of image_url ..that's it

Comment: if you want to display multiple images you need multiple image controls

Comment: I used two but only last image was displayed in both the image controls. Could you explain how to use multiple image controls?

Comment: see my expanded answer

Comment: Thanks once again! I will try this

Comment: I am getting error of "can't apply indexing with [] to an expression of type IEnumerable<XElement>

Comment: convert it to a list

Answer (score 0):

this is garbage and should not even compile

```
BOOK_URL.Source = BOOK_URL.Source + "\n"+ 
   ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(result.Element("image_url").Value));
```

assuming that `BOOK_URL` is an `Image` control, you want to do

```
BOOK_URL.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(result.Element("image_url").Value));
```

note that if you have multiple image urls, only the last one in the loop will be assigned

if you have two image controls, you could do this

```
IEnumerable<XElement> images = xdoc.Descendants("similar_books").
                                    Descendants("book").
                                    Descendants("image_url");

image1.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(images[0].Value));  
image2.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(images[1].Value));
```

Comment: so that means there is no way to get all values of image_url ? only the last value of image_url could be displayed?

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple image controls.  Or a template driven control like CarouselView or CollectionView or a bindable layout.